# Customer and Partner Portal Roles

Tags: standard-objects, portal

I'm trying to query the Customer and Partner Portal Roles.
I was able to find the PartnerRole, UserRole objects but didn't find any CustomerRole one.

Are these the objects I need to query?
How do I find out about the Customer Portal roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one.  Customer Portal Roles (as well as Partner Roles) are stored in the [UserRole](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_role.htm) object. The [PartnerRole](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_partnerrole.htm) object is picklist definition object which defines the values for for [AccountPartner.PartnerRole](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_accountpartner.htm), much like [OpportunityStage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitystage.htm) does for Opportunity.Stage.

To distinguish between regular, partner portal, and customer portal roles filter on the PortalType field.  For example:

```
List<UserRole> standardUserRoles = [select id from UserRole where portalType = 'None'];
List<UserRole> customerPortalRoles = [select id from UserRole where portalType = 'CustomerPortal'
List<UserRole> partnerPortalRoles = [select id from UserRole where portalType = 'Partner'];
```

Also, as a general tip, if you're looking to familiarize yourself with the standard Salesforce object data model head straight to the [Standard Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_objects_list.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) section of the [Web Services API Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm).